# Changing src of an image when mouseover area

Tags: javascript, html, image, src, area

What I want : when my cursor is overing the area `#ota-tail`, the `img` change to another image, and when we stop overing, the original image come back.
I've got nothing in my console with below code:

```js
$(function(){

  $("#ota-tail").hover(function(){
    $("#ota-img").eq(0).attr('src','about/about_tail.png');
  }, function(){                      $("#ota-img").eq(0).attr('src','about/about_null.png');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="ota-img test" src="public/js/about/about_null.png" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
<area id="ota-tail" alt="queue de l'otarie" coords="353,376,399,408,403,429,295,430,324,383" shape="poly">
<area id="ota-body" alt="corps de l'otarie" coords="472,288,582,332,543,388,463,409,399,408,353,375,404,306" shape="poly">
<area id="ota-paw" alt="patte de l'otarie" coords="510,397,540,389,562,428,509,428" shape="poly">
<area id="ota-head" alt="tête de l'otarie"  coords="595,164,526,184,486,224,471,287,583,332,594,249" shape="poly">
</map>
```

Comment: Image ID you have used in HTML id="ota-img test" and Script is two different. Can you confirm whether both are the same ID

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for that:

```
#ota-img{
   background-image: url('about/about_tail.png');
}

#ota-img:hover {
   background-image: url('SOURCEFORTHEIMAGEYOUWANT');
}
```

Another option is to use JavaScript:

```
<img src='about/about_tail.png' onmouseover="this.src='SOURCEFORTHEIMAGEYOUWANT';" onmouseout="this.src='about/about_tail.png';" />
```

Comment: No, I want the image to change only when we fly over the area, with your solution, the whole image will be counted in the hitbox.
The final goal is to have several areas on the same image.

Comment: That's not true. Look what you say: "When my cursor is overing the area #ota-tail, the img change to another image, and when we stop overing, the original image come back". Right, that's what you got from me